# Access NATed network service behind dynamic public IP from the local network

Tags: iptables

I have a dynamic public IPv4 address configured on my router. There is a TCP based service running somewhere behind that router at 192.168.1.11:8448. With a dynamic DNS I can access this service using a hostname:port without problems.

However, when I'm in that network, I want to connect to this same service with the same hostname. I can't connect by other means, as the service's client relies on SRV records. If the address would be static, I could put an iptables rule like

```
-t nat -A OUTPUT -d publicip -s local/net -j DNAT --to-destination=192.168.1.11
```

However this obviously doesn't work with dynamic addresses; how could I solve this? (Creating local DNS zone is not an option, I'm not an admin there)

Comment: I am doing something like that here `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0.101 ! -p esp -j SNAT --to-source \`ip addr show eth0.101 | grep inet | awk ' { print $2 } ' | cut -f1 -d "/"\``

Comment: This won't work if the interface gets reconfigured by the DHCP daemon.